# iframe redirects to a new window Phonegap IOS

Tags: ios, wordpress, cordova, iframe

I have the following problem:

I have a "blog" with wordpress where articles are.

If i want to open them on my phonegap app it doesnt embed the youtube. Instead it opens a new tab in safari and opens the youtube there in fullscreen.

I already tried to change the preferences in the config.xml but it doesnt work. Does anyone have a solution ?

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.test.test2" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25" />
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
<preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
<preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
<preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
<preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true"/>
<feature name="LocalStorage">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
</feature>
<name>Diessner App</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="http://*.youtube.com" />
<feature name="Console">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
</feature>
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
</feature>
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
```

And this is the code in wordpress:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yATi9gtGu00?list=PLEGN1LNTeit5Dsvn4wEH7zR1gCwOZTKEP?rel=0" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```